# Insert a Checkbox into every cell and assign it to that cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add a checkbox to every cell which is linked to that cell.  When checked it will return true, when unchecked it returns false into the cell it is assigned to.

The worksheet has thousands of cells, and as I'm going through inserting them manually, I realize there has to be a better solution.

The sheet I am working on looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go, Clinton.

```
Sub AddCheckBoxes()

Dim cb As CheckBox
Dim myRange As Range, cel As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheets("mySheet") 'adjust sheet to your needs

Set myRange = wks.Range("A1:A10") ' adjust range to your needs

For Each cel In myRange

    Set cb = wks.CheckBoxes.Add(cel.Left, cel.Top, 30, 6) 'you can adjust left, top, height, width to your needs


    With cb

        .Caption = ""
        .LinkedCell = cel.Address

    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are the man, thank you for saving me over 8 hours of tedious work!

Comment: @ClintonWarren, as an FYI, I posted this because I had it pretty readily available. However, a google search would have yielded this same type of answer in about 3-5 minutes.

Comment: this works beautifully. Many thanks I have just one suggestion is there a way to have the cell link move and size with each cell? I have to go through hundreds of check boxes that need to size and move with cell. I still love this solution thank you

Comment: @user2533460 -> if you use the intellisense, I bet you can find the property that marks off the move and size property. Or at worse case, you can use the macro-recorder to get the right code.

Comment: This is sort of a cheat though.  The checkboxes aren't actually IN the cells, just floating on top of them.  It's a shame that Excel doesn't really support true controls tied to cells.  It seems like it'd be a pretty basic feature to have...

Answer (score 5):

Here is generic VBA macro that I used to add centered checkboxes to all selected cells:

```
'ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Delete ' optional to delete all shapes when testing
Dim c As Range, cb As CheckBox

For Each c In Selection
    Set cb = c.Worksheet.CheckBoxes.Add(c.Left + c.Width / 2 - 8.25, _
            c.Top + c.Height / 2 - 8.25, 0, 0)  ' 8.25 is cb.Height / 2
    cb.Text = vbNullString                      ' to clear Caption
    cb.LinkedCell = c.Address(0, 0)             ' Example A1 instead of $A$1
    cb.Name = "cb" & cb.LinkedCell              ' optional
Next

Selection.NumberFormat = ";;;" ' optional to hide the cell values
Selection = True ' optional to check all at once (or 'selection = [#N/A]' for all xlMixed)
```