# Excel VBA code that sets checkbox when cell behind isn't empty

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, excel-2013

I'm new here (and beginner in VBA). I tried to modify this code to set checkbox only for cells in Range("B21:B40") which aren't empty.

Code is not ready. I m not sure how to build two for each loops working pararell that one will check content in Range("B21:B25") and next in Range("A21:A25") will set checkboxes

```
Sub ActiveCheckBox()

Dim setRange As Range, cel As Range
Dim checkRange As Range, cel1 As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim cb As Checkbox

Set wks = Sheets("InterFace")
Set setRange = wks.Range("A21:A25")
Set checkRange = wks.Range("B21:B25")

For Each cel1 In checkRange
    If cel1 <> "" Then
        For Each setRange In checkRange
            Set cb = cel.Worksheet.CheckBoxes.Add(cel.Left + cel.Width / 2 - 8.25, _
                    cel.Top + cel.Height / 2 - 8.25, 0, 0)  ' 8.25 is cb.Height / 2
                    With cb
                    .Text = vbNullString                      ' to clear Caption
                    .LinkedCell = cel.Address(0, 0)             ' Example A1 instead of $A$1
                    .Name = "cb" & cb.LinkedCell              ' optional
                    End With
        Next
    End If
Next

setRange.NumberFormat = ";;;" ' optional to hide the cell values

End Sub
```

To build that i used code from this topic [Script to Insert a Checkbox into every cell and assign it to that cell in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804899/script-to-insert-a-checkbox-into-every-cell-and-assign-it-to-that-cell-in-excel/46525740#46525740)
Please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: What kind of Checkbox is it? via Formcontrol, or from ActiveX?

Comment: You have `For each *cel1*` and then later you have `*cel*.left` without the 1.  You don't need 2 for loops as you only need to go through the cells once.  If you go through the *checkRange* column B, you can check is the cell in column A is empty using `cel.offest(0,-1)` e.g. `if cel.offset(0,-1) <> "" Then` and place a checkbox in the cell using *set cb = cel.worksheet......*

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon Thanks for help!!

Below i posted working code.
Additionaly i added:
Macro runs when sheet changed and delete checkboxes before putting new.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim setRange As Range, cel As Range
Dim checkRange As Range, cel1 As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim cb As Checkbox

Set wks = Sheets("InterFace")
Set setRange = wks.Range("A18:A30")
Set checkRange = wks.Range("A18:A30")

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    cb.Delete
Next

For Each cel In setRange
    If cel.Offset(0, 1) <> "" Then
        Set cb = cel.Worksheet.CheckBoxes.Add(cel.Left + cel.Width / 2 - 8.25, _
                    cel.Top + cel.Height / 2 - 8.25, 0, 0)  ' 8.25 is cb.Height / 2
                    With cb
                    .Text = vbNullString                      ' to clear Caption
                    .LinkedCell = cel.Address(0, 0)             ' Example A1 instead of $A$1
                    .Name = "cb" & cb.LinkedCell              ' optional
                    End With


    End If
Next
End Sub
```