# Excel Check Boxes via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am attempting to add check boxes to a worksheet using VBA.  I have a couple of variations of the code, which achieve the same result.  While the first few check boxes are aligned within the active cell, after a few rows the check boxes sink lower and lower, eventually appearing in the next row down.
How can I resolve this issue.

```
.CheckBoxes.Add(Left:=.Cells(ToRow, "B").Left, Top:=.Cells(ToRow, "B").Top, Width:=.Cells(ToRow, "B").Width, Height:=.Cells(ToRow, "B").Height).Select
```

Excel Check Boxes

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804899/insert-a-checkbox-into-every-cell-and-assign-it-to-that-cell/41899024#41899024

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code for 100 rows and it is working fine. Also please make sure that zoom factor should be at 100%. If not, then you can set it using:

ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100

```
Sub test()
    Dim ToRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MyLeft As Double
    Dim MyTop As Double
    Dim MyHeight As Double
    Dim MyWidth As Double
    LastRow = 100
    For ToRow = 2 To LastRow
            MyLeft = Cells(ToRow, "B").Left
            MyTop = Cells(ToRow, "B").Top
            MyHeight = Cells(ToRow, "B").Height
            MyWidth = Cells(ToRow, "B").Width

            ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select
             With Selection
                .Caption = "1"
                .Value = xlOff
                .LinkedCell = "B" & ToRow
                .Display3DShading = False
            End With
    Next ToRow
End Sub
```

Comment: I get the same result no matter if using my existing workbook or a new spreadsheet.  With the code provided, no checkbox in row 1, by row 10 creeping into the row below, with final checkbox appearing in row 102

Comment: I have now run the code starting at different rows and find that no matter if you start on row 2 (col b), row 12 (col c) or row 20 (col d) the boxes in each column align, so this isn't a progressive each box gets positioned a little lower issue. I don't know how to add a screen shot to display my comment

Comment: And what excel version are you using??

Comment: Office 365 Pro Plus

Comment: have you checked zoom factor? It should be 100

Comment: yes, it's set to 100.  doesn't even matter if I work from the bottom up.  the higher number the row the more the box slips.